# PayPal API: Which transactions can or cannot be retrieved with "GetTransactionDetails"

Tags: paypal

At the following doc:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/

It is mentioned: 
"Note: The details for some kinds of transactions cannot be retrieved with GetTransactionDetails. You cannot obtain details of bank transfer withdrawals, for example."

And indeed, if I use the "TransactionSearch" API and then call "GetTransactionDetails" with each returned TransactionId, some of the calls to "GetTransactionDetails" fail.

But I couldn't find any specifics about what transactions can or cannot be called with GetTransactionDetails?

Does anyone know that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are sending over in the API call, and what is coming back in the API call such as the API response.

Comment: The only input to the “GetTransactionDetails” is the TransactionId (string). If you pass certain transaction id, such as some of the RecurringPayment type of transactions returned by TransactionSearch, you get something like "Invalid transaction Id" or something like that...

Comment: Its working when I test it.  I would need the response so that I can check the logs on my end.  The response should contain a time stamp and a correlation id that I would need.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, here is an example (this is in the paypal sandbox, not production). CorrelationId: 914e11cec3092 - Timestamp:  7/05/2013 10:35:41 PM - Error short message: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.

Comment: For anyone wondering which type of transactions can be retrieved with GetTransactionDetails, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476437/paypal-transaction-types-for-which-no-details-can-be-retrieved-via-api for some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving an error because you are passing over "I-30PA9BJX6HCX" for the transaction id.  This is not the transaction id.  This is the profile id.  You would need to pass over the transaction id.  I checked the profile's transaction history and I do not see any successful transactions having been processed for this transaction.  It looks like you created the profile and suspended it and reactivated it a few times, but it has never billed.  The next payment date is set to May 25, 2013.  It should bill on that date.  If you are wanting to test the GetTransactionDetails API call, you could pass over the transaction id as "3DC84483CN537843X".  This is the transaction id for another transaction that was successfully processed on your account.  If you are trying to get the details about a profile, you would want to use the GetRecurringPaymentProfileDetails API call, then with that call you could pass over the profile id "I-30PA9BJX6HCX".

Recurring Profile Details.

Date Event By From To Reason/Notes
Apr 30, 2013 Profile Reactivated Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 ProfileSuspended Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 Profile Reactivated Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 ProfileSuspended Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 Profile Reactivated Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 ProfileSuspended Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 Profile Reactivated Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 ProfileSuspended Merchant
Apr 25, 2013 Profile Created Merchant

Comment: Thanks you're right but that Id was returned by the call to "TransactionSearch" (in the field called "TransactionID") so my question is how do I know when an item returned by "TransactionSearch" is a true transaction I can call “GetTransactionDetails” with, or not, like in this case.

Comment: The transaction search returns it, because it is a record in your transaction history.  All of the recurring profiles will start with I-, your transactions id's will not start with I-.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean T- for transactions? In which case I guess only the T-* are valid identifiers for GetTransactionDetails.

Comment: Your transactions id's will not start with "T-", they will be a combination of letters and numbers, and they would not have a "-" in the transaction id.  Profile ID's would have the "-" in them, they would start with "I-"