# PayPal transaction types for which no details can be retrieved via API

Tags: paypal, transactions

Does anybody know the PayPal transactions types (from API point of view) for which PayPal does not provide details when using GetTransactionDetails API?

The official documentation is very frugal regarding this topic:

" You cannot obtain details of bank transfer withdrawals, for example."

Thank you.

Comment: In Documentation regarding the response from GetTransactionDetails is written:

TRANSACTIONTYPE -  The type of transaction. It is one of the following values: cart, express-checkout. My assumption is that only for these 2 transactions types details are available at all.

Comment: As you already have found that's not true. When you use SearchTransaction API you receive other transaction types.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume anything that doesn't pertain to the API itself can't be retrieved via API. You can't start a bank transfer via the API so it would make sense that you can't get the details either.

Comment: Lets assume we have a list of transactions downloaded by executing SearchTrasnaction API. The question is - how could I know having only transaction's type and status for which of these transactions PayPal will reject my GetTransactionDetails request by responding "no details available for this transaction"?

Comment: Can you post some sample data in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the details for a bunch (600+) of transactions and I found the following types:

```
1. Fee Reversal
2. Payment
3. Refund
4. Temporary Hold 
5. Transfer
```

By just testing it appears that you cannot get transaction details for the types `Fee Reversal` and `Transfer`.

According to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/#transactionsearch-response-fields there are some more transaction types, so you might find some other transaction type descriptions.